# Cannot find module '@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux' error after expo build:ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am stuck as I am unable to make ios build from expo. I am getting

```
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Cannot find module '@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux'
```

this error when I am trying to run expo build:ios from my ubuntu. 
I also tried installing @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux module but no progress.

Following are expo diagnostics

```
  Expo CLI 3.17.23 environment info:
System:
  OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
  Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.18.0 - /usr/bin/node
  npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
npmPackages:
  expo: ^37.0.7 => 37.0.7 
  react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
  37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
  react-navigation: ^2.12.0 => 2.18.3 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 3.17.23
```

This is very annoying and I didn't find any suitable solution yet. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Edit : Added expo diagnostics

Comment: Please attach the output of `expo diagnostics`

Comment: @Mugen Please check now.